# Not able to start wso2 api manager

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am getting errors and warnings while trying to bring up wso2 api manager 4.1.0 on windows.
It keeps saying like this:

> KeyManagerConfigurationdataretriever failed retrieving key manager configuration from remote endpoint.Trying after 300 seconds....

Error is:

> ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper An unknown exception has been captured by the global exception mapper.
> feign.FeignException$InternalServerError: [500 ] during [GET] to [https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration] [OpenIDConnectDiscoveryClient#getOpenIdConnectConfiguration()]: [<!doctype html>HTTP Status 500 ΓÇô Internal Server Errorbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-colo... (455 bytes)]
> at feign.FeignException.serverErrorStatus(FeignException.java:231) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:180) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:169) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at jdk.proxy32.$Proxy457.getOpenIdConnectConfiguration(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getOpenIdConnectConfigurations_aroundBody814(APIUtil.java:10949) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getOpenIdConnectConfigurations(APIUtil.java:10944) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getAndSetDefaultKeyManagerConfiguration_aroundBody786(APIUtil.java:10537) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getAndSetDefaultKeyManagerConfiguration(APIUtil.java:10512) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getKeyManagerConfigurationsByOrganization_aroundBody28(APIAdminImpl.java:363) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getKeyManagerConfigurationsByOrganization(APIAdminImpl.java:333) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.internal.service.impl.KeymanagersApiServiceImpl.keymanagersGet(KeymanagersApiServiceImpl.java:47) ~[?:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.internal.service.KeymanagersApi.keymanagersGet(KeymanagersApi.java:48) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) ~[?:?]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
> [2022-05-12 11:48:50,147] ERROR - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed to retrieve Key Manager configuration with 57 times.

Comment: Whats the Windows version and the JDK version you use?

Comment: @RrR- Java 18 version and Windows 11

Comment: APIM 4.1.0 does not support JDK 18 and it has not been tested on Windows 11. This could be why you are facing issues.

Comment: You can find the product compatibility matrices here https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/reference/product-compatibility/